# Run time error 3021. 'No current record'!

Tags: vba, ms-access, delete-row

I'm trying to make a button function for deleting rows.

My code:

```
 CurrentDb.Execute " Delete * from tblAsset where AssetID = '" & Me.tblAssetsub.Form.Recordset.Fields(0) & "' "
   tblAssetsub.Form.Requery
       MsgBox "Data has been Deleted"
    Me.tblAssetsub.Requery
```

The problem is, sometimes, it gives an error when I click the button even there is a selected data. Please help me.

Comment: In which line does the error occur?

Comment: And when the error occurs, what's the value of `Me.tblAssetsub.Form.Recordset.Fields(0)`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the RecordsetClone:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim ThisID As String

With Me!tblAssetsub.Form
    Set rs = .RecordsetClone
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        ThisID = !AssetID.Value ' or what matches .Fields(0).
        While rs.EOF = False
            If rs!AssetID.Value = ThisID Then
                rs.Delete
            End If
            rs.MoveNext
        Wend
        MsgBox "Data has been deleted."
    End If
    Set rs = Nothing
End With
```

No requery will be needed.

Comment: *No requery will be needed.* This is f*ing brilliant. I always used a rather complicated function to return to the next (or previous) record after a delete via code and subsequent Requery, but this is so much easier and more user friendly. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Minor note: I would use `rs.FindFirst` to locate the matching record, or even `rs.Bookmark = Form.Bookmark`, instead of the loop.

Comment: Yes, you would normally do that for a recordset, but I guess only a handful or so records are listed in the subform, so it hardly isn't worth the trouble.